# add value with same id in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to add the value with of the displayed data in my datagridview because i cant do it in the with `query` because it is encrypted.

sample displayed:

| product | sold |
| --- | --- |
| coke | 20 |
| coke | 20 |

And here is what i want to happen:

| product | sold |
| --- | --- |
| coke | 40 |

Comment: [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) will be your solution.

Comment: @YongShun thank you sir for the idea but how to integrate it with the `datagridview`

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your results are encrypted, and then you have to decrypt them before you display them in the datagridview? Are both columns encrypted or just the name? If you are using a different key / iv per row, then yes you'd have to decrypt after retrieving the results, however, if the key / iv is for the entire table, then a row that has 'coke' is going to encrypt the same way each time, allowing you to do the group by on column (that's assuming again, the numbers column of 'sold' is unencrypted)....

Comment: ....If you do need to do the decryption on the results before feeding them into the datagridview, then I would recommend creating a data collection of the results first, and then using something like GroupBy that @Yong Shun suggested, and taking that and setting it as the DataSource for the datagridview. Reason being, is that updating the datagridview is much more expensive operation.

Comment: @B.O.B. both are encrypted so i have to decrypt them and display it. thats why im figuring out how to do it in the `DataGridView` since `query` is not and option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new grouped list after you have the initial one in code behind. You can try something like this:

```
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> productOrders = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        // Fill list of productOrders
        productOrders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("coke", 20));
        productOrders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("coke", 20));
        productOrders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("cokeX", 20));
        productOrders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("cokeX", 20));
        productOrders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("cake", 20));
        productOrders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("cokeX", 20));


        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ordersByProduct = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        foreach(var order in productOrders)
        {
            if(ordersByProduct.Where(x => x.Key == order.Key).ToList() != null && ordersByProduct.Where(x => x.Key == order.Key).ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, int> currentValueByProduct = ordersByProduct.Where(x => x.Key == order.Key).First();
                int combinedPrice = order.Value + currentValueByProduct.Value;
                ordersByProduct.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(order.Key, combinedPrice));
                ordersByProduct.Remove(currentValueByProduct);
            }
            else
            {
                ordersByProduct.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(order.Key, order.Value));
            }
        }

        // Set DataGridView to ordersBuProduct
        //return ordersByProduct;
```

In your case productOrders would be the decrypted data (you might have a class for the productOrders you don't have to use KeyValuePair). In the end set the datasource of the DataGridView to the ordersByProduct list.